# Ardutester Millenium I2c Lcd Not Showing Anything!

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, atmega328, testing

Hiii Friends....,
I am Trying to Build Components tester Using Arduino Specifically Atmega328p Chip .
I Downloaded The Ardutester Millenium Code From Here ..  https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/plouc68000/ardutester-millenium-the-ultimate-uno-mega-versions-c81db4

Edited Makefile.h By Enabling i2c lcd Interface And Adding My I2c Lcd Adress ...   But it wont work

I tried On Uno And Mega Also Serial Monitor Output seems ok But It Doesnt Display anything on 16*2 lcd

Thanks ...... :)
[image][image]

Code is available at that page sir...
Thanks for your reply

Comment: please add minimal code that exhibits the problem to your post ... also include the wiring diagram that you used to connect the modules

Comment: "By Enabling i2c lcd Interface And Adding My I2c Lcd Adress ... But it won't work", based on your schematic, it doesn't seem to be a I2C interface... Also please add your code.

Answer (score 1):

The schematic you posted is not for I2C. You have a connection to the regular 2x16 LCD character display. For the I2C an SSD1306.